# Insert a nonlinear PDE in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, scripting, character-encoding, insert

I am new to Mathematica and trying to learn its language.
I want to solve a non-linear PDE but don't know how to insert it.
Would you please help me or give me some tutorial about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[h, x, n, t]
hx = D[h[x, t], x];
ht = D[h[x, t], t];
sqrtTerm = Sqrt[1 + 4*n*Abs[hx]];
ode = -Sign[hx]*1/2*D[ h[x, t]*(sqrtTerm - 1), x] == -ht
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just do not try to solve this analytically. It wont work (Abs and Sign do not play well with analytic solvers).

May be numerical solution might work (with right IC/BC and values for any parameters.

see [DSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) and [NDSovle](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

Comment: Thank you. it makes sense and I think everything is correct except that the eq is PDE not ODE. you wrote ode =....      thanks for your suggestions, I do not want to solve it analytically its impossible, I wanted to use NDSOLVE but I could not introduce the equation in Mathematica